# Laravel pagination id

Tags: laravel, pagination

I have multiple views with search and pagination in my website. I need to check when pagination is clicked so my code will work. Problem is I'm having these pagination methods in the same file, and I want to be able to seperate whichpagination is clicked. Is it possible to give 'pagination li a' class own id, so I can recognize whick pagination is clicked? Thank you

Comment: Hi venenenela Can you add some code please ?.

Answer (score 1):

Use the third parameter of `Builder::paginate` to define the name of the page-parameter to use multiple paginations on one page:

*(example usage)*

```
Model1::paginate(20, ['*'], 'page1'); // ?page1=x
Model2::paginate(10, ['*'], 'page2'); // ?page2=x
Model3::paginate(30, ['*'], 'page3'); // ?page3=x
```